# Shift points along x axis

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to recreate a half and half plot with a box plot and points. 
Ideally, I'd like the points to be ordered to the left of the box plot and not overlapping. 
so far I've followed this -

https://github.com/h21k/R/blob/master/snippets/half_box.R

I have however removed the as.numeric function on line 29.

is it possible to shift my points to the left in his case so that they do not overlap with the box plot, or, better still arrange them in a horizontal histogram alongside each box?

I hope that's clear.

The relevant code from the script:

```
library(ggplot2);library(ggthemes)

ggplot(iris) +
  theme_stata() +
  theme(line = element_blank()) + 
  stat_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length), geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.2) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill=Species),
               alpha = 1, size = 0.75, width = 0.25, outlier.shape = 3) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1, xmax = 1.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 8, alpha = 1, fill = 'white') +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = 2.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 8, alpha = 1, fill = 'white') +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 0, ymax = 8, alpha = 1, fill = 'white') +
  geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(Species) + 0.1, colour = Species, y = Sepal.Length),
             alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if that's what you want but you can do this to arrange them one on top of the other:

```
require(tidyverse)

boxplot <- ggplot(iris) +
  theme_stata() +
  theme(line = element_blank(), legend.position="none") + 
  stat_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length), geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.2) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill=Species),
               alpha = 1, size = 0.75, width = 0.25, outlier.shape = 3)

histogram <- ggplot(iris) +
  theme_stata() +
  theme(line = element_blank()) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(Sepal.Length, fill=Species),
               alpha = 1, size = 0.75) +
  facet_grid(~Species)


ggpubr::ggarrange(boxplot, histogram, nrow = 2)
```